# Parametric equation turning into explicit form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, parametric

I came across a parametric equation: $$x=2t-2\sin (t)\\y=2-2\cos(t)$$ The question asked me to graph it on a calculator, so I graphed it. But then I questioned: is there a way to write it explicitly (like $y=f(x)$)? I tried but couldn't get the $2t$ and the trig function away the same time. In general, can I parametric equation be written explicitly?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write $x-2t=-2\sin t,\,y-2=-2\cos t.$ Then square and add to get $$(x-2t)^2+(y-2)^2=4.$$ Finally, solve for $t$ in the second equation to get $\cos t=\frac{2-y}{2}.$ Then for values of $t$ such that $0\le t\le π,$ we have $$t=\arccos\left(\frac{2-y}{2}\right),$$ so that the equation becomes $$\left(x-2\arccos\left(\frac{2-y}{2}\right)\right)^2+(y-2)^2=4.$$

Apart from the fact that this probably doesn't trace out the whole curve, since there is a restriction on $y$ so that $4\ge y\ge 0,$ it is not very pretty to look at.

We are lucky in this case to be able to get such a relationship at all. It is not always possible to do this in general.

Comment: I think your first equation should be $(x-2t)^2+(y-2)^2=4$.

Comment: @Mnifldz Right you are, and thank you too!

Comment: @Allawonder Thank you :)

Comment: It might also be worth noting that this can’t be written in the form $y=f(x)$ as the OP wanted. Not because $y$ isn’t a function of $x$, but because the solution can’t be expressed in terms of the elementary functions that we have to work with.

Comment: @abc... You're very welcome!